# How to Validate Minimum Age Greater & Equal to 18 Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-bootstrap

For the SignUp page I need to validate age is equal to or greater than 18. I have attempted using similar examples but all require me to install a dependency. I am looking for a way to achieve the desired results through React. My code is as follows

signup.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { BsFillInfoCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import Tooltip from "react-bootstrap/Tooltip";
import OverlayTrigger from "react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert'
import { UserAuth } from "../../AuthContext";

const Password = (props) =>
{
  const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);
  const togglePassword = () => {
    setPasswordShown(!passwordShown);
  }
  return(
    <div className="input-group w-75 mb-5">
          <input
            type= {passwordShown ? 'text' : 'password'}
            ref = {props.myRef}
            className="form-control shadow-none"
            placeholder="PSU1>OSU!"
            aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          ></input>
          <button onClick={togglePassword}>Show Password</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const SignUpPopup = (props) => {
    //input fields
    const firstName = useRef("");
    const lastName = useRef("");
    const email = useRef("");
    const DOB = useRef("");
    const password = useRef("");
    const passwordConfirm = useRef("");
    const [checked1, setChecked1] = useState(false);
    const [checked2, setChecked2] = useState(false);
    var errorMessage = ""

    //change handlers
    const handleChange1 = () => { setChecked1(!checked1) } ;
    const handleChange2 = () => { setChecked2(!checked2) } ;

    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const {createUser} = UserAuth();
    
    //IMPROVE THE CHECKING OF THE FORM
    function checkSignUp(){

      var success = true
      
      if (firstName.current.value === ""){
        success = false
        errorMessage += "Invalid first name\n"
      }
      if (lastName.current.value  === ""){
        success = false
        errorMessage += "Invalid last name\n"
      }
      if (email.current.value  === ""){
        success = false
        errorMessage += "Invalid email\n"
      }
      if (password.current.value  === "" ){ 
        success = false
        errorMessage += "Invalid password\n"
      }
      if (!(passwordConfirm.current.value  === password.current.value ) ){
        success = false
        errorMessage += "Passwords do not match\n"
      }

      return success;
    }

    

    async function addUserToDatabase(uid){
      fetch("URL",{
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
          body: uid
        })
    }

    async function handleSignup() {

      setError("")
      //if res == true, success, else failure and trigger alert
      var res = checkSignUp(); 
      if(res){

        //authenticate
        try{
          await createUser(email.current.value, password.current.value);
          const {user} = UserAuth();
          addUserToDatabase(user.uid);
          props.handleClose();
          props.signupNextFunc();
        }
        catch(e){
          errorMessage += "Invalid email or password"
          setError(errorMessage)
        }

      }
    }



    const changeToLogin = ()=>{
      props.handleClose()
      props.loginFunc()
    }

     
    return (
    <div className="popup-box">
      <div className="box">
        <div className="upperwrapper">
        <span className="close-icon" onClick={props.handleClose}>
          x
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={firstName}
            className="form-control shadow-none"
            placeholder="Ben"
            aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          ></input>

        </div>
        {/* LAST NAME INPUT */}
        <p style={{ fontSize: "20px", marginTop: "15px" }}>
          Last Name<span className="required-field"></span>
        </p>
        <div className="input-group w-75 mb-5">
          <input
            type="text"
            ref = {lastName}
            className="form-control shadow-none"
            placeholder="Dover"
            aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          ></input>
        </div>
          {/* EMAIL INPUT */}
          
        <p style={{ fontSize: "20px", marginTop: "45px" }}>
          Email<span className="required-field"></span>
        </p>
        <div className="input-group w-75 mb-5">
          <input
            type="text"
            ref = {email}
            className="form-control shadow-none"
            placeholder="bendover@email.com"
            aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          ></input>
        </div>

        <div className="d-flex bd-highlight mb-3 example-parent">

        <p style={{ fontSize: "20px", marginTop: "10px" }}>
          Date of Birth<span className="required-field"></span>
        </p>

        <div  style={{ display: 'block', marginLeft: "-3px", marginTop: "-8px" }}
              className="align-self-center p-2 bd-highlight col-example">
          <OverlayTrigger
            delay={{ hide: 450, show: 300 }}
            overlay={(props) => (
              <Tooltip {...props}>
                Please provide your date of birth to validate...
              </Tooltip>
            )}
            placement="right"
            >
            <div><BsFillInfoCircleFill /></div>
          </OverlayTrigger>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div className="input-group w-75 mb-5">
          <input
            type="date"
            ref={DOB}
            className="form-control shadow-none"
            placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
            aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          ></input>
        </div>

           )
```

};
export default SignUpPopup;

Any help or guidance to the right path is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might not get a lot of answers because it requires reading a lot of code. If you can simplify your example down to the relevant parts, it will be easy for someone to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate age on `onChange` of input

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const year = e.target.value.split("-")[0];
    const age = currentYear - year;
    if (age < 18) setError("Invalid age");
}

<input
    type="date"
    className="form-control shadow-none"
    placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
    aria-describedby="button-addon2"
    onChange={onChange}
/>
```